# Labeling points of a list in plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

A list of georeferenced points is:

```
coord = {{3.54231*10^6, 5.43395*10^6}, {3.54235*10^6, 
  5.43395*10^6}, {3.54239*10^6, 5.43396*10^6}, {3.54231*10^6, 
  5.43398*10^6}, {3.54235*10^6, 5.43399*10^6}, {3.54239*10^6, 
  5.434*10^6}, {3.5423*10^6, 5.43402*10^6}, {3.54234*10^6, 
  5.43403*10^6}, {3.54238*10^6, 5.43404*10^6}, {3.54229*10^6, 
  5.43406*10^6}, {3.54233*10^6, 5.43407*10^6}, {3.54237*10^6, 
  5.43408*10^6}, {3.54228*10^6, 5.4341*10^6}, {3.54232*10^6, 
  5.43411*10^6}, {3.54236*10^6, 5.43412*10^6}}
```

I would like to label each point of this list with the number of the position of the point in this list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`BubbleChart` with a custom function for the tooltip content:

```
 labelingfunc[v : {x_, y_, w_}, i_, ___] := 
 Placed[Grid[{{"point ", i}, {"coordinates", {x, y}}}, Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> Left], Tooltip];
 BubbleChart[(Append[#, 1] & /@ coord), 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Style[#, "Subsection"] & /@ Range[Length@coord], Center],
 BubbleSizes -> {0.1, 0.1}, LabelingFunction -> labelingfunc]
```

[image: labeled bubbles]

Comment: @ kguler, this is a very nice idea, thanks a lot!! Harald

Comment: @Harald, glad it may be useful.

Comment: A perfect example of what I talked about [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277/121). +1  (Harald, if you read this comment, take no offense; I mean only that your question if fairly basic for the regulars around here, but kguler took it as an opportunity to give a much richer answer than might be given.)

Answer (score 6):

How about using `Tooltips`? For example:

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[Tooltip[#1, First@#2] &, coord]]
```

[image]

Comment: @ R.M., thanks a lot for your tip!! Harald

Answer (score 6):

After a method shown [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Nov/msg00565.html):

```
c2 = Transpose[{coord, Range@Length@coord}];

{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} =
  {{Min@#1, Max@#1}, {Min@#2, Max@#2}} & @@ (coord\[Transpose]);
dx = (xmax - xmin)/6; dy = (ymax - ymin)/6;
plotrange = {{xmin - dx, xmax + 2*dx}, {ymin - dy, ymax + dy}};

shiftText = dx/2;

Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02],
  Map[{Point[#[[1]]], Style[Text["Pt " <> ToString[#[[2]]],
       {#[[1, 1]] + shiftText, #[[1, 2]]}], 12, Black]} &, c2]},
 PlotRange -> plotrange, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you choose the `Ordering[coord]` labels for a particular reason? To make this consistent, you´d have to use `c2 = Transpose[{Sort@coord, Ordering[coord]}]` as well, right?

Comment: @ Yves, you are quite right.  I have replaced it with `Range@Length@coord`.

Comment: @ Yes and @ Chris, thanks a lot for your help!! Harald